# Movie where a man is talking to a parasite in his stomach

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I wanna say it's an old movie. Maybe late 80s. I saw it a few years ago once. I'm assuming it's sci-fi horror; I'm pretty sure it's about aliens/parasites.

There's a scene with a man in bed, and he's talking to a parasite in his stomach. It moves, and he tries to calm/control it. I know at one point he says "Atta boy" but that's all I can muster up.

There was another scene where a girl was in the bathroom too, I’m pretty sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: I wanna say it’s an old movie. Maybe late 80s. I saw it a few years ago once.

Comment: @DavidW there was another scene where a girl was in the bathroom too I’m pretty sure

Comment: Similar to / Potentially X-Files episode "Humbug" [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbug_(The_X-Files)) - series 2, episode 20

Comment: May be *Alien*, but the conversation is short ;-).

Comment: @Allen Uh hm. Late 80s is old. No comment ;-).

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.

Answer (score 23):

Is this David Cronenberg's ***[Shivers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073705/)*** (1975)...?

> The residents of a suburban high-rise apartment building are being infected by a strain of parasites that turn them into mindless, sex-crazed fiends out to infect others by the slightest sexual contact.

There's a scene about 33 minutes into the film where a man named Nick is lying in bed talking to several man-made parasites squirming within his abdomen, and he does say "attaboy" at one point. While this is occurring, his wife, Janine, is crying in the bathroom, as she knows there's something wrong with him, but he won't explain what's going on.

There's also a later scene where a parasite enters a woman's body while she's taking a bath.

You can view part of the first scene I mentioned in the video clip below. Nick says "attaboy" at around the 0:45 mark.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a film, but this sounds an awful lot like the first episode featuring a Trill in Star Trek: TNG, [The Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Host_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can improve this answer if you quote relevant portions of the plot from the linked page to demonstrate how this matches the question.

Comment: That episode does involve a character with a symbiotic lifeform in his abdomen, however, I don't believe there's a scene where he's lying in bed talking to it and says "attaboy." Also, the OP didn't mention any sci-fi elements other than the parasite, which would be odd if they were thinking about an episode of _Star Trek._